# Android boot password security

Tags: security, boot, password

I recently purchased a security solution software for Android (Antivirus + additional security features). Before the installation, my phone started like this:

1. Android logo
2. Password
3. Phone manufacturer animation
4. SIM1 PIN, SIM2 PIN

After the installation, the order of the boot events has changed:

1. Android logo
2. Phone manufacturer animation
3. SIM1 PIN, SIM2 PIN
4. Password

Is this order more or less secure? What settings have been changed? Why does my phone ask password only after SIM PIN?

Comment: Android today uses [File Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/file-based) that doesn't require a password on boot. Its screen lock authetication is cryptographically tied to encryption. Password on boot used to be there when android was using [Full Disk Encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk). Password at boot doesn't make it any more secure than what it already is with file based encryption.

Comment: @defalt - why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @Rohit Gupta The difference between FBE & FDE has become too repetitive as an answer. It is now a common knowledge that FBE doesn't need password on boot.